# column header not changing untill i click on it

Tags: java, swing

I have a jtable ,,,its header have a pop up menu from which u can change the header but the changes are not being visible untill i click on the header...pls help

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class MyCustomHeaderRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
String colmNameToChange;
int colomHeaderClicked;

public MyCustomHeaderRender(String nameRecieved, int coloum) {

    colmNameToChange = nameRecieved;  
    colomHeaderClicked = coloum;     
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {

    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if (colomHeaderClicked == column) {
        setOpaque(true);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(colomHeaderClicked).setHeaderValue(colmNameToChange);
        table.getTableHeader().repaint();
        table.repaint();

    }

    return c;
}

}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A renderer has nothing to do with changing the text of the column. It only paints the text of the column. So get rid of the renderer.

Instead you need to actually update the `TableColumn` to contain the new column name.

So the code would be something like:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(...);
tc.setHeaderValue(...);
table.getTableHeader().repaint();
```

Comment: @anrdggle, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Everything is god but can u tell me the reason why the Header is not visible once i press the cancel button on the JOptionDialog box as i am taking the header name as input

Comment: @anrdggle, `JOptionDialog` - what is a JOptionDialog? There is no Swing component with that class name. Be specific when you ask a question. We are not here to guess what you mean. `why the Header is not visible once i press the cancel button` - I have absolutely no idea what your logic is doing so no I can't guess what the problem might be. If you have a problem then create a new question and post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.